# Upload button C# check for MD5 hash before uploading file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, md5

I have a block of code which would upload the file into the Google Drive. My main issue here is that when the user clicks on the upload button, the MD5 hash of the file will be checked and compared with the MD5 hashes of other files in the Google Drive and if there is a duplicate, then a message pop-up should be displayed stating that the file is a duplicated file and the user would need to reupload the file again.

This is from my GetGoogleDrive.cshtml file.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    <p>
        <label for="file">Upload file:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="fileUpload" />
        <script>
            $('#fileUpload').click(function (e) {
                if ($('#file').val() === "") {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Nothing',
                        text: 'No file selected',
                        type: 'error',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Again!!',
                        timer: 4000

                    })
                }
                else {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Wait awhile...',
                        text: 'File will be uploaded shortly',
                        type: 'success',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Okay, cool',
                        timer: 4000
                    })
                }

            });
        </script>
```

The following code is for my upload file controller class.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        GoogleDriveFilesRepository.FileUpload(file);
        return RedirectToAction("GetGoogleDriveFiles");
    }
```

This is the code for my Google Drive Files model class.

```
public static void FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            DriveService service = GetService();

            string path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/GoogleDriveFiles"),
            Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            file.SaveAs(path);

            HashGenerator(path);
            compareHash(HashGenerator(path));

            var FileMetaData = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
            FileMetaData.Name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            FileMetaData.MimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);

              FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request; 

              using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            { 
                request = service.Files.Create(FileMetaData, stream, FileMetaData.MimeType);
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }

        }

    }
```

Where should I generate the MD5 hash value of the file? In the C# or the JS?

Comment: If you are wanting to keep from wasting your and your users' bandwidth, generate the hash on the client side and check it with the server first; that way you can tell them it's a duplicate before uploading. But be aware that anything on the JavaScript side can be modified, meaning malicious users could "trick" the server by sending a fake hash, so depending on your needs you might want to generate the hash on the server *after* uploading instead of, or in addition to, on the client side.

Comment: I have tried searching around for how to do that with razor but im not getting any fruitful references. Do you have any reconmendations on how to do it or the idea for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link hash code with file uploaded in .net using Google Drive Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57855505/how-to-link-hash-code-with-file-uploaded-in-net-using-google-drive-rest-api)